# Is there a way to find space element(ASCII: 32) between strings in C

Tags: arrays, c, scanf, buffer

I'm learning how `scanf()` uses a buffer in C.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[80];

    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("1st word: %s\n", str);
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("2nd word: %s\n", str);
    scanf("%c", &str[0]);
    printf("buffer: %d\n", str[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

and I enter `apple jam` as input.
I thought that the third `scanf` would take the space(`' '`)from the buffer.
But the result was different.
It took `'\n'`, the newline character from buffer.

I thought that the result would be like:

```
1st word: apple
2nd word: jam
buffer: 32
```

but the result was:

```
1st word: apple
2nd word: jam
buffer: 10
```

Since the 1st `scanf("%s", str);` takes the word `apple` from the buffer and the 2nd `scanf("%s", str);` takes the word `jam` from the buffer, I thought that the buffer still contains `' '` and `'\n'`.

So I expected that the result would be `buffer: 32`.
However, the third `scanf` (`scanf("%c", &str[0]);`) took the newline character from the buffer.

Where can I find a space character (`' '`)?

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%s", str);` reads and discards any whitespace characters from standard input (this causes input to be requested from the terminal and you input is read as a full line that does not have any whitespace character at the beginning) and then reads any non whitespace characters into the target array `str`. With your input, you get `apple` in `str`, `scanf()` returns `1` successful conversion and `printf("1st word: %s\n", str);` outputs `1st word: apple` and a newline as expected.

The next call `scanf("%s", str);` does the same thing, so the space you type is just read and discarded, `str` receives `jam`, `scanf()` returns `1` successful conversion and the `printf("2nd word: %s\n", str);` outputs `2nd word: jam` and a newline as expected.

The next `scanf("%c", &str[0]);` reads the newline character that was input when you hit the <kbd>enter</kbd> key after `apple jam` and stored it into `str[0]`, this newline character has the value `10` on your system which presumably uses ASCII. `scanf()` returns `1` and `printf("buffer: %d\n", str[0]);` outputs `10` as a consequence.

Note that you should write `scanf("%99s", str)` to avoid undefined behavior on overlong input and you should test the return value of `scanf` to detect invalid or missing input.